# Change WebView behavior to simulate a Cocoa interface element

Tags: cocoa, webview

I create a view for my application that use a WebView to render special contents thanks to CSS. **I need to stop this 2 behaviors inherit directly from WebView**:
1) Mouse scrolling up and down over this view produce a bounce effect like in safari or in IOS browser (i think this is true only for Lion) 
2) At the right click over this view appear a contextual menu with the only voice "Reload"

I can't completely stop mouse events over this view because user might select text from this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

- `[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] setAllowsScrolling:NO];`
- add a [WebUIDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/WebUIDelegate) which implements [`-webView:contextMenuItemsForElement:defaultMenuItems:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3acontextMenuItemsForElement%3adefaultMenuItems%3a)
   and returns an empty array.